# how to run back-end (Non-Stop process) process without affect the Ui Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

My problem is :
              I am trying to run a continues non-stop process from the time of activity created to destroyed. if i do it the UI Thread stop the execution / unable to access any UI in my emulator..,

Is there any way to do it?

Guide me please..

Comment: Use a service : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: thank you! i try now itself..,

Answer (score 2):

@forgivegod is right (about the service), that will get you in the background.  However, if your process is really tightly coupled with an Activity (i.e. you want it to match the lifecycle by starting on Activity start and stopping on Activity stop, instead of running outside of that lifecycle) then I think an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would get you what you need.

Comment: I'd say an asynctask if you're needing to interact with the UI, or just a straight thread if you know what you're doing. Gets rid of the overhead of all the Google stuff that comes with an Asynctask

Comment: @o0rebelious0o I would never recommend using a Thread (particularly to someone who needs to ask how to get off the main thread).  That 'overhead' is very important, as it allows the system to manage tasks and resources.  Why would you tell someone to learn it the wrong way just because it's a few more lines of code.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying but Asynctasks aren't without their limitations and restrictions. Depends what is needed. You're right though, for someone needing to ask those sort of questions threads aren't the best idea. I use threads as they are executed by non-ui activity classes, which as you no doubt know, rules out Asynctasks as they can only be instantiated on the UI thread

Comment: i did use the AsyncTask..,

Comment: Thank You!i unable to find the option as answered for my question. where to mark as answered?..,